# Ruby: How to access an api using HTTParty

Tags: ruby, http-post, httparty

I'm new to Ruby, and to using HTTParty, and was trying to follow the HTTParty examples from their [github page](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/basic.rb) to execute a basic POST. When I run the code below I get an error:

```
require 'pp'
require 'HTTParty'
require 'pry'

class Partay
    include HTTParty
    base_uri "http://<myapidomain>/search/semanticsearch/query/"
end

options= {
    query: {
        version: "0.4",
        query: "lawyer"
    }}

response = Partay.post(options)

puts response
```

The error I get is:

```
rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/common.rb:715:in `URI': bad argument (expected URI object or URI string) (ArgumentError)
from ~/.ruby/2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.3/lib/httparty/request.rb:47:in `path='
from ~/.ruby/2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.3/lib/httparty/request.rb:34:in `initialize'
from ~/.ruby/2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.3/lib/HTTParty.rb:539:in `new'
from ~/.ruby/2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.3/lib/HTTParty.rb:539:in `perform_request'
from ~/.ruby/2.2.0/gems/httparty-0.13.3/lib/HTTParty.rb:491:in `post'
from json-to-csv.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

What I am looking for is calling a post that receives JSON in the same way that calling this URL works:

```
http://somedomain.com/search/semanticsearch/query/?version=0.4&query=lawyer
```

Comment: Consider using Unirest, its much simpler and very readable. www.unirest.io

Answer (score 0):

Noting a solution with the suggested gem - [unirest](http://unirest.io/ruby.html):

```
require 'unirest'

url = "http://somedomain.com/search/semanticsearch/query"
response = Unirest.post url, 
                        headers:{ "Accept" => "application/json" }, 
                        parameters:{ :version => 0.4, :query => "lawyer" }
```